# What is the optimal way to create a scrollable column with space between items?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Something I encounter alot is creating a scrollable column with space between items.

```
SingleChildScrollView(child: 
Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, 
children: ...))
```

This doesn't work unless you give the `Column` a fixed height.

`ListView`s don't set space between.

What is the best way to do this? Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try ListView.separated. It has separatorBuilder to give space between items.

More info on official doc
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use `spaceEvenly`, just use

```dart
body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [..]
```

But to make it scrollable,
You can include `SizedBox` on column to have fixed/dynamic space between item.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text("top widget"),
      SizedBox(
        height: 200,
      ),
      Text("bottom widget"),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Or better

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column( 
          children: [
            Text("top widget"),
            SizedBox(
              height: constraints.maxHeight * .4,
            ),
            Text("bottom widget"),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

More about [`layout`](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)